# Foundation for WP not respecting min-height 100% for div

Tags: css, wordpress, zurb-foundation

So working with Zurb foundation and wordpress, and trying to implement 100% height divs for a fixed scrolling bg.

[Essentially trying to apply this solution](http://codyhouse.co/gem/alternate-fixed-scroll-backgrounds/)

I have the HTML in place etc. but for some reason, and firegbug isn't showing me how or where the 100% height for my divs is either being overwritten or just flat out ignored.

[Current implementation](http://pixelneer.com/)

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Height of 100% in CSS always means "make me the same height as my parent element". It can't do anything if the parent does not have explicit height.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to force them via js:

```
jQuery(".yourdiv").each( function() {
    jQuery(this).css('height',jQuery(window).height());
  });
```